# pandas import error when run from command prompt

Tags: python

[image]

I dont have any issues when run it through spyder or jupyter

Comment: if you use pip what is the output of `pip freeze` ? (Or better can you see your pandas version when you execute `pip freeze`)

Comment: Check for PYTHONPATH environment variable. The path mentioned should have pandas package installed there

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that you have python2 and python3, and pandas it is installed on one of them (let's say python3) and you are trying now to `import pandas` from python2 interpreter

you can check for your interpreter path to see if it is the same everywhere:

```
import sys
sys.executable
```

Comment: I dont have python 2 , sys.executable gave right path and code works, however, to_csv is not creating an output file, however when i run from IDE code is creating a csv file

Answer (score 2):

Did you set up a kernel from a virtual environment for your Jupyter? Are you sure that pandas is not installed only in that virtual environment?

Can you try to activate the virtual environment before you import pandas?

Comment: I currently have default environment base(Root). Do i have to create new environment and activate it?

Comment: You should not have to create a new environment since you clearly already have one that has pandas installed. Try to identify this environment (the one used by Jupyter) and activate it.
Otherwise, yes you can always create a virtual environment for this project, install pandas and then call pandas from the command prompt but I would not recommend you to work on the same project with two different virtual environments.